# Почему имена полей в формате json для встроенной сущности надо указывать в lowercase?

Tags: java, json, веб-программирование, jpa

Имею сущность:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "contact_channel")
public class ContactChannel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "channel_name")
    private String channelName;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "contact", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "contact_channel_id"))
    private List<Contact> contact = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Встроенную сущность:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Embeddable
public class Contact {
    @Column(name = "c_type")
    private String cType;

    @Column(name = "c_value")
    private String cValue;
}
```

Контроллер:

```
    @PostMapping("/save")
    public ContactChannel save(@RequestBody ContactChannel contactChannel) {
        return contactChannelRepository.save(contactChannel);
    }
```

Когда передаю json с именами полей как в сущностях:

```
{
  "id": 31,
  "channelName": "test_f2fbd4301322",
  "contact": [
    {
      "cType": "test_0e2d4fca0ea9",
      "cValue": "test_d2587c69ac60"
    }
  ]
}
```

То уже в контроллере получаю в полях cType и cValue значение null.

Когда передаю json с именами полей у встроенной сущности в lowercase:

```
{
  "id": 31,
  "channelName": "test_f2fbd4301322",
  "contact": [
    {
      "ctype": "test_0e2d4fca0ea9",
      "cvalue": "test_d2587c69ac60"
    }
  ]
}
```

то поля заполняются корректно.
Почему так происходит? И можно ли сделать так чтобы использовать имена полей с учетом регистра?

Comment: попробуйте пример ниже и отпишитесь

Comment: Спасибо! С @JsonProperty заработало корректно.

Comment: Можете тогда галочку слева от ответа поставить) тут так спасибо говорят)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Странное поведение - лично мне такое не встречалось и поля всегда использовались регистрозависимые.

---

Можно попробовать явно задать имя поля, которое будет использоваться при сериализации/десериализации.

Для этого над полем необходимо проставить аннотацию, в которой можно указать название поля.

В зависимости от используемых адаптеров `Jackson` / `Gson` они могут отличаться

- `Jackson` использует аннотацию `@JsonProperty("___")`
- `Gson` использует аннотацию `@SerializedName("___")`

**Jackson**
*Насколько я понимаю у Вас должен использоваться именно он*

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Embeddable
public class Contact {
    @JsonProperty("cType")
    @Column(name = "c_type")
    private String cType;

    @JsonProperty("cValue")
    @Column(name = "c_value")
    private String cValue;
}
```

---

**Gson**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Embeddable
public class Contact {
    @SerializedName("cType")
    @Column(name = "c_type")
    private String cType;

    @SerializedName("cValue")
    @Column(name = "c_value")
    private String cValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Спецификация [ECMA-404](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-404_2nd_edition_december_2017.pdf#page=11) не накладывает ограничения на регистр, уникальность или порядок следования ключей. Это зависит от конкретной реализации API или спецификации. Именование же ключей JSON в нижнем регистре де-факто является общепринятым стандартом.
Если к Вашему вопросу, то у каждой библиотеки де/-сериализатора имеется конфигурация, которая позволяет указать различные параметры сериализации/-десериализации, правил обработки отсутствующих значений и т.д.. Если мы говорим о Jackson, то для этого можно использовать метод `ObjectMapper.configure`:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
```

У [MapperFeature](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html) ещё много параметров, которые можно сконфигурировать. Вариант с декорированием полей необходимыми именами тоже рабочий, но может быть утомительным при:

- большом количестве полей
- переименовании кода
- невозможности изменить код классов

---

#### Ссылки по теме:

- [ECMA-404 2nd Edition](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-404_2nd_edition_december_2017.pdf)
- [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html).[configure](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#configure(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature,%20boolean))([MapperFeature](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html) f, boolean state)
- [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html).[configure](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#configure(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature,%20boolean))([SerializationFeature](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html) f, boolean state)
- [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html).[configure](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#configure(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature,%20boolean))([DeserializationFeature](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html) f, boolean state)

Comment: плюсик вам от соседнего ответа за конфигурацию Jackson'а