# Jackson не должен создавать поля, которые не были переданы

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, jackson

Методом PATCH я передаю объект dto пользователя, содержащий только изменяемые поля.
В RestController Spring, в Patch методе я получаю его в body, и те поля, которые я не передавал создаются со значением null. И в сервисе не понятно, как с ними работать - толи я не передавал эти поля, толи хочу обнулить их значения.

Подскажите, как настроить Jackson, чтобы он не создавал поля, которые не передаются?

```
import lombok.Data;

import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

@Data
public class UserDto {
    Long id;

    @NotBlank
    String name;

    @Email
    @NotBlank
    String email;
}
```

На скриншоте, в контролер передается объект `{"email": "updateName@user.com"}` и в контроллере поле `name` появляется со значением `null`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поля вы создали сами и поскольку они не были инициализированы, то сохраняют свое значение `null`. Попробуйте инициализацию полей дефолтными значениями, которые соответствуют `@NotBlank`. Так что настроить Jackson наверное не получится. В этот вопрос следует включить больше подробностей и уточнить проблему.

Comment: А как тогда стоит поступить для случая, если я хочу в patch поменять email и не трогать имя? В сервис же прилетит dto в которой новый email и name - null. И если не игнорировать - перепишем существующее значение. Если игнорить все null'ы - упустим сознательное обнуление поля

Comment: Для обработки трёх состояний можно поиграться с использованием `Optional` для полей, тогда при десериализации `null` может означать отсутствие поля, `Optional.empty()` - поле со значением `null`.  Однако имеет также смысл пересмотреть логику и при патчинге просто игнорировать поля со значением `null` (отсутствующие), обновляя только поля с _новыми_ значениями, а для _удаления_ значений в `nullable` полях предусмотреть отдельный метод.

Comment: Недавно только отвечал: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1449116/182750